# Marker on Google Map on Android NOT aligned

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I placed succesfully many marker on the my Map Activity in my Android APP.

The problem is that when zoom is low (i see an entire country on the screen) i see that the marker is not aligned at all to the set position. i mean that the marker, at low zoom level, seems to be placed 50-100km away from that point.

My marker is a simple drawable icon  that have an upside TRIANGLE in the center, so the lower corner of the icon (that is placed in the real bottom-center of the icon) should be exactly placed on the GPS coords i set for the marker. Instead it seems that the aligned point is the bottom-left corner of the icon...

how to set marker-icon alignment?

Comment: Add answers as an answer; it's ok (and appropriate) to answer your own question.

Comment: i have less than 100 reputation... so i can't add an answer to my question before 8 hours... i added the answer as update to remind me about the text to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution myself.
i was using standard Overlay inherited class.

i modified the instruction in the overrided draw function:

```
public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow,
        long when) {
    Point screenPts = new Point();
    mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, screenPts);
    Point finalDrawPosition= new Point();
    finalDrawPosition.set(screenPts.x - (bmp.getWidth()/2), screenPts.y- bmp.getHeight());

    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, finalDrawPosition.x, finalDrawPosition.y, null); 
    [...] 
    }
```